Redirecting to /home When Entering URL with Route Parameter
I'm encountering a strange behavior in my Angular application. When I navigate to a route with a date parameter using a link within the app, it works perfectly. However, when I copy and paste the same URL into a new tab, it automatically redirects to /home.
example of URL: http://localhost:4200/home/2024-04-10
Further context:

I believe the behavior to be new. We recently updated our codebase to angular 17, I don't know if it could be related
The logic in HomeComponent that handles the parameter never gets triggered, the redirect occurs before, which make me think that it must be related to the routing module, even though I left it barebone in the course of my debugging process:

Home module:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: 'home/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'home/:date',
    component: HomeScreenComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

root routing module:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: {
      customizing: CustomizingResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-properties',
    component: ResetPropertiesComponent,
    data: {
      redirectTo: '/auth/login',
    },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled'    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

I'd be thankful, if not for a solution, then for some paths I could explore, as I am now at a loss.

please share the URL with the problem, try commenting out the redirect and see if it fixes it

example of URL: http://localhost:4200/home/2024-04-10

If this is your root module, should't it be RouterModule.forRoot(routes)? also are you having this issue in development server?

commenting out the redirect did not help... it now just redirects to "/" instead of "/home"

It's not the root routing module. I've added it to my post. I've already tried to comment out the redirect there too, without effect.

Your root routing module is missing the routes for the child module.
const routes: Routes = [
  {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: {
      customizing: CustomizingResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-properties',
    component: ResetPropertiesComponent,
    data: {
      redirectTo: '/auth/login',
    },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled'    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

You can change the child routing to
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':date',
    component: HomeScreenComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

